# Oracle newly created user privileges issue?

Tags: database, oracle, privileges

Does newly created user: 

`create user John 

identified by secret;`


 have some privileges? Or is there any oracle config for privileges of newly created user? I need information about this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, no privileges.

```
select * from dba_sys_privs where grantee='JOHN';

select * from dba_tab_privs where grantee='JOHN';

select * from dba_role_privs where grantee='JOHN';
```

Answer (score 1):

ammoQ is technically correct.

Given the user created as above does not have CREATE SESSION privilege, it cannot actually log on yet, or do anything else.

It is possible for another user with an appropriate CREATE ANY ... privilege to create objects (such as procedures, functions, triggers) under JOHN's schema/user. If so, then JOHN would automatically have privileges to drop those objects (but without a CREATE SESSION privilege, it would be difficult for them to achieve that).

From a security point of view, Oracle does have a bunch of privileges granted to PUBLIC. Once a user is created they do have a bunch of things they can do (eg select from views such as ALL_USERS).